# Is there a simpler construct for Python map(None, fcn())?

Tags: python, dictionary, equivalent

The documentation for Python `map()` states in part:

> If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed;

Therefore, if I have some Python code like this:

```
def yearsback(tbl, yb):
    def fcn():
      y = None
      i = 0
      for (year, prefix, suffix) in reversed(sorted(tbl.iterkeys())):
        if y == None:
          y = year
        elif y > year:
          i, y = 1 + i, year
        if i >= yb:
          return
        yield (year, prefix, suffix)
    return map(None, fcn())
```

Is there a simpler way to write that?  Also, I suspect the `reversed(sorted(tbl.iterkeys()))` could also be simplified.

Comment: Depends. What is `fcn()`? Why won't `return list(fcn())` do?

Comment: @StoryTeller I've added `fcn()`.

Comment: `sorted(tbl.iterkeys(), reverse=True)`

Comment: @chepner The iterkeys() don't come out sorted already?

Comment: Assuming `tbl` is a dictionary, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you would need to do is -

```
list(fcn())
```

If you want an iterator, use -

```
iter(fcn())
```

Comment: In this case, I think `iter` would be a no-op, right? Since a generator is already an iterator?

Comment: He's updated his question since.  I'll leave it in case it helps anyone in the future.